# org.hibernate.MappingException:Repeated column in mapping for entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have the following Entity class and another class for composite primary keys

**Entity class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROJECTS")
public class Project {
private Integer SlNo;
private Long projectNo;
private Date projectDate;

@EmbeddedId
ProjectPK projectPK;
```

**Primary Key class**

```
public class ProjectPK implements Serializable {

private Integer SlNo;
@Column(name = "project_no", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Long projectNo; 

public ProjectPK(){
}
// with getters and setters and equals and hashCode implementation
```

The problem is  I am getting the following exceptions

```
:org.hibernate.MappingException:Repeated column in mapping for entity
: test.Project column: projectNo (should be mapped with
insert="false" update="false")
```

I have added the following in `Project Entity` class, but I get the same exception

```
@Column(name = "project_no", insertable = false, updatable = false)
```

**Edit 1**

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<Long> countQ = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
Root<Project> empCount = countQ.from(Project.class);
countQ.select(cb.count(empCount));

TypedQuery<Long> countquery = entityManager.createQuery(countQ);// error in this line
```

Comment: I think you have to make SlNo read-only too. You can still read it in your code but you'll have to use the ProjectPK object to update it...

Comment: @PierreHenry I have tried SlNo read only like projectNo, however that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue  by the following manner

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROJECTS")
public class Project {
@Column(name = "SL_NO" , insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Integer SlNo;
@Column(name = "PROJECT_NO" , insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Long projectNo;
private Date projectDate;

@EmbeddedId
ProjectPK projectPK;
```

and Primary Key class

```
@Embeddable
public class ProjectPK implements Serializable {
@Column(name = "SL_NO")
private Integer SlNo;
@Column(name = "PROJECT_NO")
private Long projectNo; 

//with hashCode and equals implementation
```

Answer (score 3):

Why are you declaring `SlNo` and `projectNo` fields twice ? Just remove them from from the `Project` class and it should be fine.

Or, even better, remove the `ProjectPK` class and modify the `Project` class to the following (note that this method only works with Hibernate) :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROJECTS")
public class Project implements Serializable {

  @Id
  private Integer SlNo;

  @Id
  private Long projectNo;

  private Date projectDate;
}
```

Comment: If I remove `SlNo` and `projectNo` from `Project` class, how can I refer these fields from other class e.g. from DAO for `Entity` class columns?

Comment: I have the following in DAO Class `Predicate predicate = cb.equal(
    emp.get(Project_.projectNo), pexp);` where `Project_` is `metamodel` generated class. So if I remove `projectNo` from Project class, it gets removed from Project_ class as well and I wouldn't be able to refer as `Project_.projectNo`.

Comment: Add delegate getters for those fields in the Project class or take a look at the second solution I posted in my edited answer

Comment: I have removed `ProjectPK` and ended up with the following exception at runtime `No supertype found; nested exception is ja
va.lang.IllegalStateException: No supertype found`.

Comment: Project needs to implement Serializable.

Comment: It does have `Serializable` implementation

Comment: I think the error is not related to your mapping anymore. Given the comment you left on the other answer it looks like you hit the following Hibernate bug : https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7216

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7216) I have added as `@EmbeddedId
 ProjectPK projectPK;` in generated sql query all column names are converted as java variable names instead of sql columns.

Comment: There is nothing "mentioned" in the link I gave you. It's just a report for an Hibernate bug that hasn't been fixed yet ... In other words, you need to change your count query but the mapping I gave you is fine.

Comment: Is is mentioned that with @EmbeddedId it works though. I tried to download the attachment, however link is broken.

Comment: I have resolved the issue, see my answer. Thanks anyways. One question though is it better to add `insertable = false, updatable = false)` in Entity or Primary Key class?

Comment: None because you shouldn't duplicate the fields, that's the whole point of the answer I gave you ...

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your desired behavior, you can use the @IdClass annotation as shown below -

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/IdClass.html

Here is the modified code -

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROJECTS")
@IdClass(ProjectPK.class)
public class Project {
   @Id
   private Integer SlNo;

   @Id
   private Long projectNo;

   private Date projectDate;
}


public class ProjectPK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="sl_no")
    private Integer SlNo;

    @Column(name = "project_no")
    private Long projectNo; 
}
```

Comment: Quote from Hibernate documentation : "This approach is inherited from the EJB 2 days and we recommend against its use. But, after all it's your application and Hibernate supports it."

Comment: Thanks for the quote. I'll keep that in mind. But, as long as it is in the specification, I think we should be safe. We have used it in our project and had no problems.

Comment: @Sashi I am getting run time exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No supertype found`at this line in DAO `TypedQuery<Long> countquery = entityManager.createQuery(countQ);`

Comment: @Sashi I have added my query part is Edit 1

Comment: Good to know that. You may post your solution for the benefit of other users.

Answer (score 1):

It has been for awhile. Your last code doesn't seem to be right. You created a compound key, but didn't use it. It shall be the following:

```
@Entity
public class Project {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ProjectPK projectPK;
    ...

}
```